# Splitting text file's lines that starts with a specific character into separate files

Tags: bash

Is there a one line solution for this in bash for moving all the sentences that start with a same integer to a same file (preserving their order)?

```
0 ||| the shortage of snow in mountain stirred hoteliers 
....
0 ||| the shortage of snow in mountain stirred hotel
1 ||| the runways deserted pose any problem that operators ski .
...
1 ||| the runways deserted do not pose a problem that operators of ski .
2 |||
...
```

To move the lines that start with the same number into a separate files 0, 1, 2, and so on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely:

```
awk '{print > $1".txt"}' file
```

This uses `awk` to get the first field of each line and use it as a file name (together with ".txt"). Then, `print` outputs to the given file.

For your given input, look at the output:

```
$ tail *.txt 
==> 0.txt <==
0 ||| the shortage of snow in mountain stirred hoteliers 
0 ||| the shortage of snow in mountain stirred hotel

==> 1.txt <==
1 ||| the runways deserted pose any problem that operators ski .
1 ||| the runways deserted do not pose a problem that operators of ski .

==> 2.txt <==
2 |||
```

---

As seen in the comments, if there are maaaaany different first fields, `awk` can complain for having so many open files. If so, you can close them after printing:

```
awk '{file="$1".txt"; print >> file; close(file)}' file
```

It is important to remark that we need to use `>>` to append. Otherwise, every time we will be removing all the previous content in the file.

Comment: awesome. It works, but complains about having too many files open. As expected the number of files created will be somewhere between 2000-4000 files.

Comment: Mmmm then you can probably close them after printing: `awk '{file=$1".txt"; print > file; close(file)}' file`. Could you give a try?

Comment: it doesn't complain anymore :), but seems to overwrite the same file. So every file only has one single line in it now.

Comment: @user3639557 Oooops then we should use `>>` to append instead of `>`! My fault I didn't mention it before.

Comment: perfect :) great :) awesome :)